# SymmetricDS clustering for high availability

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, symmetricds, windows-clustering

I have setup a SymmetricDS node on Azure Windows Server 2016 using Azure SQL for both master and slave databases. I now want to setup SymmetricDS Clustering in high availability mode. I went through the documentation as follows but it's very thin and I have some outstanding questions.

https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/user-guide.html#_clustering

Q1> How to setup clustering on Windows Azure?

Q2> What will be the change in the configuration like sync.url etc? I am not able to guess the exact URL for clustering.

Q3> Is there any latest blog post available with the detailed list of steps from the SymmetricDS team?

Q4> Is professional or paid support available for configuration of SymmetricDS Clustering in high availability from the SymmetricDS team or community or any third party vendor?

I am using SymmetricDS version 3.8.40.

Regards

Rajat Agrawal

Comment: SQL Azure has built-in HA.  So I am unsure why you would need to do these steps at all...

Comment: I need HA for the database synchronization process that is been taken care by the SymmetricDS server. I need a setup so that if 1 node goes down the other can continue doing the syncing process.

Comment: I see - thanks for the clarification.  I can't speak to symmetricds's HA configuration.  (I can speak about SQL Azure's).  Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

The user guide on SymmetricDS was written with an active-active cluster in mind, meaning each node in the cluster is running simultaneously.  They all use the same engine properties file, so they are contacted at the same sync.url and connect to the same db.url.  (The database itself is usually already clustered or highly available.)  The sync.url actually points to a load balancer that connects to one of the available backend SymmetricDS servers.  Here is a blog article explaining it:

http://www.jumpmind.com/blog/load-balancing-symmetricds-with-apache